# Includes taking a long time to load and you can see them loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-load

I’m including one HTML file in another, as a way to reuse my header and navigation generation logic.

The trouble is that when I browse to pages on my site, I can see the HTML that *isn’t* included in the include files load first. Only then you can see the menus and banners load afterwards. I’d like everything to appear to load at the same time.

Here's the [rendered HTML](http://pastebin.com/eRUh7Diy).

And here’s a code snippet showing you how I generate these pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includeHeader").load("includes/templates/header.html");
      $("#includeNavigation").load("includes/templates/navigation.html"); 
    });
    </script>
    <div id="includeHeader"></div>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="includeNavigation"></div>
```

I’m currently working with the code to try to move any external libraries / CSS to the bottom of the page vs. in the header. But so far, that hasn’t really changed or improved anything.

Comment: Hi, if you are loading in HTML from a static path, you should really use a server side language such as PHP.  If you really need to use javascript, you don't need to use doc ready. eg `$(...)` (it's shorthand)

Comment: @MrBizle , yeah... the only server side lang i have available on this server is lua.  I will have to look around to figure out how to embed lua in html / vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the templating languages.

If your includes are simple HTML files then you could use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Dust](http://www.dustjs.com/) - you could just copy your code and that's it, then in Javascript you would need just render these templates - see the documentation.

You could use [Jade/Pug](http://jade-lang.com/demo/) instead, but its syntax is different from the HTML, so that's not just question of copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(handler)` to load them, which is a form for [`$.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler). So it waits for the document to load everything before loading your `header.html` and `navigation.html`.

Try

```
  <head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="includeHeader"></div>
    <script> 
      $("#includeHeader").load("includes/templates/header.html");
      $("#includeNavigation").load("includes/templates/navigation.html"); 
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: it strange to define div tag under head tag. :)

Comment: @HareshVidja, Yeah, I had just realized it and was fixing. I just copied from OP without realizing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the load function does not run until the document.ready event has fired. Which is probably after your page has started rendering. To get everything to appear at the same time you could use the callback from .load to show everything. So everything is hidden,

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    /// show your stuff
});
```

You will of course need to know both has loaded.

I would recommend not using javascript to render HTML from a static path and would use a server side lang instead for speed.

Comment: ok.  i'm familiar with php but the only lang i have available on this specific server is lua.  will have to find some resources that show me how to embed lua in html or vice versa i guess

Answer (score 0):

I think it make some level fast its not waiting for load all dom element, I am considering `#includeNavigation` element is under `#includeHeader` element

```
  <head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="includeHeader"></div>
    <script> 
      $("#includeHeader").load("includes/templates/header.html", function(data){
          console.log("header loaded");
          $("#includeNavigation").load("includes/templates/navigation.html", function(data){
                 console.log("navigation loaded");
          }); 
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: that doesn't work at all for me.  nothing gets included.

Comment: please check console log ... check if error not found then check url or try with full url.